# Trying to create Dancer2 custom response

Tags: perl, dancer

I'm currently trying to create a custom dancer response so that I can return my result in json, however when I run the following code, I get the error:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Dancer::Response" (perhaps you forgot to load "Dancer::Response"?) at app.pl line 11./
```

Here is the code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Dancer2;
require './commacounter.pl';

print "Running";

Dancer::Response->new(
    status => 200,
    content => 'null'
);

my $response = Dancer2::SharedData->response;

Dancer2::SharedData->response->status; #200

get '/text=:string' => sub {
    $response->content_type('application/json');
    $response->content(commacounter(params->{string}));
    return $response;
};

any qr{.*} => sub {
    status 'not_found';
    template 'special_404', { path => request->path};
};

dance;
```

Anyone know why I'm getting an error, or if there's a better way to do this?
Many thanks!

Comment: *"require './commacounter.pl'"* : What is in this file?

Comment: It just returns the number of commas in the given input

Answer (score 1):

`Dancer::Response` module not loaded. Just type:

```
use Dancer::Response;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dancer::Request is part of the original Dancer framework. If you're using [Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2), then you should be using [Dancer2::Core::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Core::Response) instead.